# How to track SyntaxNodes across Workspace.TryApplyChanges()

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'd like to track `SyntaxNode`s and `SyntaxTrivia`s across
different versions of a `Solution`/`Workspace`.

I tried annotating some nodes with `SyntaxAnnotation`s. 
This works well as long as I don't update the workspace.

Calling `Workspace.TryApplyChanges` (successfully) seems to remove
all `SyntaxAnnotation`s.

- This surprised me. Why does this happen?
- How can I track `SyntaxNode`s across workspace updates?

Example code follows:

```cs
var workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();
var project   = workspace.AddProject("TestProject", LanguageNames.CSharp);

var klass = SyntaxFactory
           .ClassDeclaration("Klass")
           .WithAdditionalAnnotations(new SyntaxAnnotation("Foo"));

var compUnit = SyntaxFactory.CompilationUnit().AddMembers(klass);
var document = project.AddDocument("TestFile.cs", compUnit);
var docId    = document.Id;
var solution = document.Project.Solution;

var root1  = document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result;
var klass1 = root1.GetAnnotatedNodes("Foo").FirstOrDefault();
var eq1    = klass1.IsEquivalentTo(klass); // returns true

var apply = workspace.TryApplyChanges(solution);  // returns true

var root2  = workspace.CurrentSolution.GetDocument(docId).GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result;
var klass2 = root2.GetAnnotatedNodes("Foo").FirstOrDefault(); // returns null, why?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because `TryApplyChanges` doesn't actually re-use your nodes as is.  Instead it "replays" the same changes as textual changes to the actual solution, and then let's the parser re-parse.

This happens for a few reasons:

1. To avoid having annotations pile up over time in the trees and interfere with each other (consider something like that formatting or rename annotations used in CodeFixes still being present after the fix was applied).
2. To protect against trees that don't round-trip from showing up in `CurrentSolution`.  It is possible to construct trees that the parser would never generate (consider changing operator precedence for example).
3. To ensure the changes are actually applied, requires changing the original representation - the files on disk or the text buffers in memory, not just using the new trees in the workspace.

You could consider using something like the [`SyntaxPath`](http://source.roslyn.io/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/R/0b515d88b639b744.html) type from the Roslyn sources to try to find an equivalent node.